# Can you define your own network protocol name in the URL?

Tags: sockets, url, connection, network-protocols

URLs are known for their format `<protocol>://<adress>:<port>`

e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com:443`

But how exactly can you define your own protocol name, such as `abc://localhost:9999`? 
Client-side you would connect to this URL just as usual. But on server-side, how do you setup a server running with the own abc protocol showing up in the URL?

Comment: Search for “protocol handlers” on this website.

Answer (score 0):

this `<protocol>://` you mention is just kind of metadata. This tells the system(OS, env) to how to deal with this URL. And actually who's responsible and can handle it?

You may register/bind your app to the OS/env. e.g. you support a protocol named `rayman`.

OS will ask your application to handle any `rayman://` URL when it is asked.